# как получить последний сегмент url через js или jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

есть

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/category/transmission-oil
```

или к примеру такой

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/es/products/category/transmission-oil
```

нужно всегда получать последний transmission-oi вместо него может быть другой

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/es/products/category/transmission-oil";
var last = url.split('/').pop();
console.log(last);
```